# Subscripts in Rmarkdown using Rstudio visual editor

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio

I´m having some trouble keeping subscript letters in place when I switch back and forth between R studio visual editor.
For some reason

```
a~1~
```

which works well when knitted transforms to

```
a\~1\~
```

if I dare switching to the visual editor.
A similar thing was happening in the previous version when citing references, but got fixed. Is there a current workaround to use subscripts in RStudio without having to worry about using the visual editor?

Thanks!

PS. I´m using the latest Rstudio version